# binding multiple ComboBoxes to 1 List<>

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

I'm trying to bind multiple ComboBoxes to a single List.  However when I select a value in 1 combobox, all ComboBoxes that are binded to List change to the same value.

```
List<Country> countryList = new List<Country>();
// Add contries to list.  There are two properties string Name, and string Code
comboBox1.DataSource = countryList;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Code";


comboBox2.DataSource = countryList;
comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox2.ValueMember = "Code";
```

Now when I select a country from comboBox1, it also select comboBox2.  I would prefer not creating a seperate list for each ComboBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Sorry you have to create a new list</strike>. If you can you just create another list.

```
comboBox2.DataSource = countryList.ToList();
```

However if that doesn't work for you you can create a separate binding Context for one of the combo boxes and do it that way

```
        BindingContext bcG1 = new BindingContext();

        comboBox1.BindingContext = bcG1;

        comboBox1.DataSource = Countries;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Code";

        comboBox2.DataSource = Countries;
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "Code";
```

Comment: What if you had a list of Singletons you wanted to use as a selection.  It looks like the databinding uses a counter internal to the list which is what causes the issue.  Is there not a databinding object that can perform this function independently?

Comment: @galford13x yep you're right, I learned something new today. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: +1: Ah yes I forgot about BindingContext. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If is only a pair, can be like this:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = Countries;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Code";

comboBox2.DataSource = Countries;
comboBox2.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox2.ValueMember = "Code";
```

If there are more, or in diffrent forms, better create a methode in a public:

```
public ComboBox bindCombo(ComboBox _cb, DataTable _dt)
{
    _cb.DataSource = _dt;
    _cb.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
    _cb.ValueMember = _dt.Columns[0].ToString();
    _cb.DisplayMember = _dt.Columns[0].ToString();
    return _cb;
}
```